# Php regex that matches substring followed by any length of character and then comma

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a long string containing **`Copyright: 'any length of unknown string here',`**
what regex should I write to exactly match this as substring in a string?

I tried this `preg_replace('/Copyright:(.*?)/', 'mytext', $str);` but its not working, it only matches the `Copyright:`

Comment: Try `'/Copyright:.*?\',/'`

Comment: thanx its working, I just missed the comma

Answer (score 3):

A lazily quantified pattern at the end of the pattern will always match no text in case of `*?` and 1 char only in case of `+?`, i.e. will match *as few chars as possible* to return a valid match.

You need to make sure you get to the `',` by putting them into the pattern:

```
'/Copyright:.*?\',/'
               ^^^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN3iK2/1)

Comment: doesn't paranthesis play any role here `(.*?)` ?

Comment: @Uttara: The `preg_replace` has a `mytext` as replacement, so, the capturing group (in the form of a replacement backreference) is not used, thus, I removed it from the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` in your group 1 `(.*?)` makes this block [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), i.e. matching as few characters as possible. Removing that would solve it.

```
Copyright:(.*)',
```

However, that would match **everything** in that same line. If you have text in that same line, make sure to limit it further. My screenshot below just just grouping `()` to make it easier for you to look, you can do without the parentheses.

[image: Demo]

I usually use [Regxr.com](http://regexr.com/) to test my regular expression, there's also many other similar tools online, note that this one is great in UX, but does not support [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).